# Read XML in PHP with simplexml_load_string

Tags: javascript, php, xml

Via javascript a XML is sent to PHP. How do can i read this XML in PHP with `simplexml_load_string`. The XML is send with `encodeURIComponent(CurtainXML)`.
When i Read the XML in PHP the variable `$unique_Id` is empty. Why is this empty?

PHP:

```
$importXml2 = urldecode($importXml);
$unique_Id = $xml->gordijn->info->windecor_reference_number

$unique_Id is empty?
```

Ajax:

```
var CurtainXML = '<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" \?><Order><Gordijn><Info>
<Commissienaam>www</Commissienaam> <StofNaam>Peyton Plus 16 zand</StofNaam> <Kleur>16 zand</Kleur> 
<windecor_reference_number>605994_8EB9366A96DE44058B7A0E903D0D9B84</windecor_reference_number> 
<Debiteur_nummer>Bakel, van Interieur</Debiteur_nummer> <Debiteur_name>110101 </Debiteur_name> </Info> 
<Gordijnsoort>Plooigordijn</Gordijnsoort> <Vertrek>222</Vertrek> <Hoogte>222.0</Hoogte> 
<Breedte>222.0</Breedte> <Verdeling>Gelijk stel</Verdeling> <Links>111.0</Links> <Rechts>111.0</Rechts>
 <Plooipercentage>227</Plooipercentage> <Type_gordijn>Comfort gordijn</Type_gordijn> <Onderzoom>Enkel 
10.0</Onderzoom> <Hoofdje>2.0</Hoofdje> <Loodjes>Ja</Loodjes> <Knippen>Ja</Knippen> 
<Strijken>Nee</Strijken> <Banen> <Totaal>3.5</Totaal> <Links>1.75</Links> <Rechts>1.75</Rechts> </Banen>
 <Memo/> <Inkoopprijs>197.11</Inkoopprijs> <Verkoopprijs>96.13</Verkoopprijs> <PlooiSpec> 
<Plooisoort>Vlinder</Plooisoort> <Plooidiepte>2.7</Plooidiepte> <Vliesband>8</Vliesband> </PlooiSpec>
 <Stof> <Naam>Peyton Plus 16 zand</Naam> <Kleur>16 zand</Kleur> <Maatsoot>BN 150</Maatsoot> 
<Leverancier>Vadain Styling</Leverancier> <Patroon>Effen</Patroon> <Stoftype>Weef/drukstof</Stoftype> 
</Stof> <Knipmaten> <Hoofd> <Knipmaat>247.0</Knipmaat> <Banen>4.0</Banen> <StofTotaal>988.0</StofTotaal> 
</Hoofd> </Knipmaten> </Gordijn></Order>';
```

Comment: Examples would be nice.

Comment: Where are you using `simplexml_load_string()` ??

Comment: $xml = simplexml_load_string($importXml2);

Comment: Try to debug `$xml` with an IDE or to `var_dump($xml)` if you don't have access to one, and look at the contents of it. Does the object look like it should? `var_dump($unique_Id)` and tell us what that looks like, too

Comment: var_dump($unique_Id) returns null

Answer (score 2):

The property names are case sensitive. It should be:

```
$unique_Id = $xml->Gordijn->Info->windecor_reference_number;
```

[Sample Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nrztdu)

Comment: Another question: you have a link to Sample Demo. How can i use to test my code?

Comment: @user3552264 there are codes below, you can check that out, its just a simple ajax sending the xml string on it, and then the PHP processing the xml and echoing the ID itself. then the server response was just used inside the `alert()` inside the success block of it.